r.walk no output band 1: SetColorTable() only supported for Byte or UInt16 bands in TIFF format
I'm trying to use r.walk GRASS algorithm on QGIS 3.28 'Firenze' (Windows) but there is no output with:

band 1: SetColorTable() only supported for Byte or UInt16 bands in TIFF format

error every time I try. Does anyone have a solution?
Wersja QGIS: 3.28.2-Firenze
Rewizja QGIS: b47e00ba601
Wersja Qt: 5.15.3
Wersja Pythona: 3.9.5
Wersja GDAL: 3.6.1
Wersja GEOS: 3.11.1-CAPI-1.17.1
Wersja PROJ: Rel. 9.1.1, December 1st, 2022
Wersja PDAL: 2.4.3 (git-version: f8d673)
Algorytm został uruchomiony: 2024-06-18T17:17:31
Uruchamianie algorytmu 'r.walk.points' …
Wprowadź parametry:
{ '-k' : False, '-n' : False, 'GRASS_MIN_AREA_PARAMETER' : 0.0001, 'GRASS_RASTER_FORMAT_META' : '', 'GRASS_RASTER_FORMAT_OPT' : '', 'GRASS_REGION_CELLSIZE_PARAMETER' : 0, 'GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER' : None, 'GRASS_SNAP_TOLERANCE_PARAMETER' : -1, 'elevation' : 'C:/Users/Wojtek/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_tRSZyo/132f673d6d424f03bb01a9ed55a71a4a/OUTPUT.tif', 'friction' : 'D:/QGIS w archeologii/12_SiteCatchment/zero.tif', 'lambda' : 1, 'max_cost' : 0, 'memory' : 300, 'null_cost' : None, 'outdir' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'output' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'slope_factor' : -0.2125, 'start_points' : 'D:\\QGIS w archeologii\\proba.shp', 'stop_points' : None, 'walk_coeff' : '0.72,6.0,1.9998,-1.9998' }

g.proj -c wkt="C:/Users/Wojtek/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_tRSZyo/d806db6f2086408999ccf3fbe3bda340/crs.prj"
r.in.gdal input="C:\Users\Wojtek\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_tRSZyo\132f673d6d424f03bb01a9ed55a71a4a\OUTPUT.tif" band=1 output="rast_6671a50c0144f2" --overwrite -o
r.in.gdal input="D:\QGIS w archeologii\12_SiteCatchment\zero.tif" band=1 output="rast_6671a50c018343" --overwrite -o
v.in.ogr min_area=0.0001 snap=-1.0 input="D:\QGIS w archeologii\proba.shp" output="vector_6671a50c01fff4" --overwrite -o
g.region n=4305033.424944233 s=4219191.533395853 e=473410.8237445056 w=350457.15045 res=83.58509401098902
r.walk elevation=rast_6671a50c0144f2 friction=rast_6671a50c018343 start_points=vector_6671a50c01fff4 walk_coeff="0.72,6.0,1.9998,-1.9998" lambda=1 slope_factor=-0.2125 max_cost=0 memory=300 output=outputa04bce4a4062499fb37a11580787e965 outdir=outdira04bce4a4062499fb37a11580787e965 --overwrite
g.region raster=outputa04bce4a4062499fb37a11580787e965
r.out.gdal -t -m input="outputa04bce4a4062499fb37a11580787e965" output="C:\Users\Wojtek\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_tRSZyo\cde1e8ecd7eb446eab86f2d68a7d0b96\output.tif" format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite
g.region raster=outdira04bce4a4062499fb37a11580787e965
r.out.gdal -t -m input="outdira04bce4a4062499fb37a11580787e965" output="C:\Users\Wojtek\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_tRSZyo\68149d0f4e844a35b06f057815da5c82\outdir.tif" format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite
Starting GRASS GIS...
UWAGA: Jednoczesne blokowanie mapsetu nie jest obsługiwane w systemie Windows
Cleaning up temporary files...
Executing <C:\Users\Wojtek\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_tRSZyo\grassdata\grass_batch_job.cmd> ...
C:\Users\Wojtek\Documents>chcp 1250 1>NUL
C:\Users\Wojtek\Documents>g.proj -c wkt="C:/Users/Wojtek/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_tRSZyo/d806db6f2086408999ccf3fbe3bda340/crs.prj"
Default region was updated to the new projection, but if you have multiple mapsets `g.region -d` should be run in each to update the region from the default
Projection information updated
C:\Users\Wojtek\Documents>r.in.gdal input="C:\Users\Wojtek\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_tRSZyo\132f673d6d424f03bb01a9ed55a71a4a\OUTPUT.tif" band=1 output="rast_6671a50c0144f2" --overwrite -o
Over-riding projection check
Importing raster map <rast_6671a50c0144f2>...
0..3..6..9..12..15..18..21..24..27..30..33..36..39..42..45..48..51..54..57..60..63..66..69..72..75..78..81..84..87..90..93..96..99..100
C:\Users\Wojtek\Documents>r.in.gdal input="D:\QGIS w archeologii\12_SiteCatchment\zero.tif" band=1 output="rast_6671a50c018343" --overwrite -o
Over-riding projection check
Importing raster map <rast_6671a50c018343>...
0..3..6..9..12..15..18..21..24..27..30..33..36..39..42..45..48..51..54..57..60..63..66..69..72..75..78..81..84..87..90..93..96..99..100
C:\Users\Wojtek\Documents>v.in.ogr min_area=0.0001 snap=-1.0 input="D:\QGIS w archeologii\proba.shp" output="vector_6671a50c01fff4" --overwrite -o
Over-riding projection check
Check if OGR layer <proba> contains polygons...
0..100
Creating attribute table for layer <proba>...
Importing 1 features (OGR layer <proba>)...
0..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Budowanie topologii dla mapy wektorowej <vector_6671a50c01fff4@PERMANENT>...
Rejestrowanie prymitywów...
C:\Users\Wojtek\Documents>g.region n=4305033.424944233 s=4219191.533395853 e=473410.8237445056 w=350457.15045 res=83.58509401098902
C:\Users\Wojtek\Documents>r.walk elevation=rast_6671a50c0144f2 friction=rast_6671a50c018343 start_points=vector_6671a50c01fff4 walk_coeff="0.72,6.0,1.9998,-1.9998" lambda=1 slope_factor=-0.2125 max_cost=0 memory=300 output=outputa04bce4a4062499fb37a11580787e965 outdir=outdira04bce4a4062499fb37a11580787e965 --overwrite
Walking costs are a=0.72 b=6 c=1.9998 d=-1.9998
Lambda is 1
Slope_factor is -0.2125
Reading raster maps <rast_6671a50c0144f2@PERMANENT> and <rast_6671a50c018343@PERMANENT>, initializing output...
0..3..6..9..12..15..18..21..24..27..30..33..36..39..42..45..48..51..54..57..60..63..66..69..72..75..78..81..84..87..90..93..96..99..100
Initializing directional output...
0..3..6..9..12..15..18..21..24..27..30..33..36..39..42..45..48..51..54..57..60..63..66..69..72..75..78..81..84..87..90..93..96..99..100
Reading vector map <vector_6671a50c01fff4@PERMANENT> with start points...
Znajdowanie ścieżki kosztu...
0..2..4..6..8..10..12..14..16..18..20..22..24..26..28..30..32..34..36..38..40..42..44..46..48..50..52..54..56..58..60..62..64..66..68..70..72..74..76..78..80..82..84..86..88..90..92..94..96..98..100
Writing output raster map <outputa04bce4a4062499fb37a11580787e965>...
0..3..6..9..12..15..18..21..24..27..30..33..36..39..42..45..48..51..54..57..60..63..66..69..72..75..78..81..84..87..90..93..96..99..100
Writing output movement direction raster map <outdira04bce4a4062499fb37a11580787e965>...
0..3..6..9..12..15..18..21..24..27..30..33..36..39..42..45..48..51..54..57..60..63..66..69..72..75..78..81..84..87..90..93..96..99..100
r.walk wykonane. Peak cost value: 80804.4
C:\Users\Wojtek\Documents>g.region raster=outputa04bce4a4062499fb37a11580787e965
C:\Users\Wojtek\Documents>r.out.gdal -t -m input="outputa04bce4a4062499fb37a11580787e965" output="C:\Users\Wojtek\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_tRSZyo\cde1e8ecd7eb446eab86f2d68a7d0b96\output.tif" format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite
**ERROR 6: C:\Users\Wojtek\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_tRSZyo\cde1e8ecd7eb446eab86f2d68a7d0b96\output.tif, band 1: SetColorTable() only supported for Byte or UInt16 bands in TIFF format.**
Checking GDAL data type and nodata value...
2..5..8..11..14..17..20..23..26..29..32..35..38..41..44..47..50..53..56..59..62..65..68..71..74..77..80..83..86..89..92..95..98..100
Using GDAL data type <Float64>
Exporting raster data to GTiff format...
UWAGA: Too many values, color table cut to 65535 entries
2..5..8..11..14..17..20..23..26..29..32..35..38..41..44..47..50..53..56..59..62..65..68..71..74..77..80..83..86..89..92..95..98..100
r.out.gdal wykonane. File <C:\Users\Wojtek\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_tRSZyo\cde1e8ecd7eb446eab86f2d68a7d0b96\output.tif> created.
C:\Users\Wojtek\Documents>g.region raster=outdira04bce4a4062499fb37a11580787e965
C:\Users\Wojtek\Documents>r.out.gdal -t -m input="outdira04bce4a4062499fb37a11580787e965" output="C:\Users\Wojtek\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_tRSZyo\68149d0f4e844a35b06f057815da5c82\outdir.tif" format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite
**ERROR 6: C:\Users\Wojtek\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_tRSZyo\68149d0f4e844a35b06f057815da5c82\outdir.tif, band 1: SetColorTable() only supported for Byte or UInt16 bands in TIFF format.**
Checking GDAL data type and nodata value...
2..5..8..11..14..17..20..23..26..29..32..35..38..41..44..47..50..53..56..59..62..65..68..71..74..77..80..83..86..89..92..95..98..100
Using GDAL data type <Float32>
Input raster map contains cells with NULL-value (no-data). The value nan will be used to represent no-data values in the input map. You can specify a nodata value with the nodata option.
Exporting raster data to GTiff format...
2..5..8..11..14..17..20..23..26..29..32..35..38..41..44..47..50..53..56..59..62..65..68..71..74..77..80..83..86..89..92..95..98..100
r.out.gdal wykonane. File <C:\Users\Wojtek\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_tRSZyo\68149d0f4e844a35b06f057815da5c82\outdir.tif> created.
C:\Users\Wojtek\Documents>exit
Execution of <C:\Users\Wojtek\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_tRSZyo\grassdata\grass_batch_job.cmd> finished.
Cleaning up temporary files...
Execution completed in 9.90 sekund
Wyniki:
{'outdir': 'C:\\Users\\Wojtek\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\processing_tRSZyo\\68149d0f4e844a35b06f057815da5c82\\outdir.tif',
'output': 'C:\\Users\\Wojtek\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\processing_tRSZyo\\cde1e8ecd7eb446eab86f2d68a7d0b96\\output.tif'}

Wczytywanie warstw wynikowych
Poniższe warstwy nie zostały prawidłowo wygenerowane.
• C:/Users/Wojtek/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_tRSZyo/68149d0f4e844a35b06f057815da5c82/outdir.tif
• C:/Users/Wojtek/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_tRSZyo/cde1e8ecd7eb446eab86f2d68a7d0b96/output.tif
Możesz sprawdzić "'Dziennik komunikatów" w głównym oknie QGIS, aby znaleźć więcej informacji na temat przetwarzania algorytmu.


This messages comes from GDAL, not from GRASS GIS. Please check if you do have pixel values and just an unfortunate color table (so, simply assign a new one in QGIS) or if the output is entirely empty.  If you can provide the data and the steps I may try it out at my end,
